# Rest parameter without losing a property

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function:

```
const something = ({params: {large, small}, ...rest}) => {
    // large and small is used here
    // then:
    otherFunction(rest);
}
```

My issue is that `params` has other parameters that I need in the `otherFunction` with the `rest`. Please note that I am not allowed to create a second parameter for the `otherFunction`.

Is there a simple, elegant solution to keep the `params` property in the `rest`? Or do I have to write a `restParams` that I merge with the `rest`?

Comment: In that case why use the destructuring within the parameters? You can just have a single parameter e.g. `args` then do `const { params: { large, small } } = args;` *inside* the function before calling `otherFunction(args);`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just for keeping things very short, because the code where this is, is too complicated already for new lines. I know it sounds bad. But I guess, I still have to use something like you wrote because there is no simpler solution.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work. Just merge the two objects together.

```
const something = (params, rest) => {
    let obj = {...params, ...rest}
    // large and small is used here
    // then:
    otherFunction(obj);
}
```

Comment: Maybe something similar can be used here, but with only one parameter in the `something`.

Comment: This is a different function signature entirely; it's expecting two positional arguments, both objects. That's **not** what the OP's currently code expects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OP said *Please note that I am not allowed to create a second parameter for the otherFunction*, they did not say the same applied for `something()`

Comment: That's true, but also we have no idea what's calling this. Your suggestion doesn't actually give easier access to `large` and `small` (I'm assuming they're in `params`, but maybe not) and this may mean adding to the caller to split an existing object across two new objects for negligible gain.

Comment: *Easier access* has nothing to do with the question, its about passing a single object to `otherFunction()` that has the two objects `params` and `rest` merged together.

Comment: @RolandRácz if you only want 1 param for `something()` then merge the two objects before you pass them in.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options

As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616316/rest-parameter-without-losing-a-property/55616826#comment97926137_55616316), don't use destructuring in your parameters if you need the variable in its original state. Use a plain parameter and use the destructuring assignment separately in your function to get the values you need:

```js
const something = (args) => {
  const { params: { large, small } } = args;

  console.log(small);
  console.log(large);
  
  console.log(args);
}

something({
  params: {
    large: 3,
    small: 2
  },
  test: "value",
  test2: 2
});
```

Or you could change your arrow function into a function expression and use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to get the first parameter as it was originally:

```js
const something = function({params: {large, small}, ...rest}) {
  console.log(small);
  console.log(large);

  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

something({
  params: {
    large: 3,
    small: 2
  },
  test: "value",
  test2: 2
});
```